# convert alias command from tcsh to bash

Tags: bash, csh, tcsh

I'm new to bash.
I want to convert below alias command form tcsh to bash:

```
alias buzz 'echo \!$;if (-e ~/.sshelp.txt) grep -i \!$ ~/.sshelp.txt && echo \!$;if (-e ~/.sshelp_qct.txt) grep -i \!$ ~/.sshelp_qct.txt '
```

I tried below command but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
alias buzz= 'echo \!$;if (-e ~/.sshelp.txt) grep -i \!$ ~/.sshelp.txt && echo \!$;if (-e ~/.sshelp_qct.txt) grep -i \!$ ~/.sshelp_qct.txt '
```

Comment: Why not use `function` in your `.bashrc`. it would be simpler to read at least and would not warrant much escaping of quotes.

Comment: Remove the space after the =

Comment: @JonathonK Somewhat irrelevant, because most of the body is invalid `bash` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function in `bash`. C shells define aliases because they don't support functions. I *think* the following is (roughly) equivalent.

```
buzz () {
    echo "$1"
    if [ -e ~/.sshelp.txt ]; then
        grep -i "$1" ~/.sshelp.txt && echo "$1"
    fi
    echo "$1"
    if [ -e ~/.sshelp_qct.txt ]; then
        grep -i "$1" ~/.sshelp_qct.txt
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried above code but it gives an error: syntax error near unexpected token `{

Comment: I put above code inside ~/.alias file and then sourcing .alias file inside .bashrc

Comment: Update, If I put above code directly inside .bashrc then it works fine. But if I put it in ~/.alias file and then source it inside ~/.bashrc then it breaks.